# Rails: prepend_before_action in superclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, before-filter, operator-precedence

I have an authentication method in my ApplicationController that I always want to run first. I also have a method in an subcontroller that I want to run after the authentication method, but before the other ApplicationController before_actions. In other words, I want this:

```
ApplicationController
before_action first
before_action third

OtherController < ApplicationController
before_action second
```

The above causes the methods to be called in order of: `first` -> `third` -> `second`.
But I want the order to go: `first` -> `second` -> `third`.

I've tried using prepend_before_action, like so:

```
ApplicationController
prepend_before_action first
before_action third

OtherController < ApplicationController
prepend_before_action second
```

But this causes it to go `second` -> `first` -> `third`.

How do I get the order to be `first` -> `second` -> `third`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `prepend_before_action`like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :first
  before_action :third
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :third, :second
end
```

Comment: Rails handles the arguments to `prepend_before_action` and `before_action` in exactly the same way -- can you explain why this works? It seems like it would end up calling `:third` two times.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, and see if it works:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :first
  before_action :third
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :third
  before_action :second
  before_action :third
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in all my subclasses I'll have to add this workaround though. I was hoping there was some way I could modify the ApplicationController to achieve the result.

Comment: If it is in the majority of your controllers, you can run :second_action in the parent and skip in the few children.